# Internal web page to retrieve, save and store information?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, intranet

(I apologize for any incorrect lingo)

I am creating an internal web page  as a sort of intranet for me and another associate to use in our department to keep track of information. I have created "pages" using HTML to navigate and saved in our department folder. Doesn't need to be flashy just functional.

I have a table with 5 columns of information for each item we need filled out. I have created a pop-up window and form for these 5 columns to open and the idea is that when the the user (me) fills the form out and clicks the submit button, the information is transferred to the parent page, saved and stored for later tracking.

I'm assuming this isn't possible by just saving .html files into our network folders. I think i might need a database to "save" the information the user filled out.

I wouldn't necessarily need the window pop-up..

Is this way over my head?

Comment: Depends how much time you have, you seem to understand vaguely what you need to do. Have you any experience programming? Maybe search google for free, off the shelf products that will do this

Comment: What have you tried? also Yes you need to have Database to store info that you want to save, but lets say you already have DB attached and have all desired columns etc, you can redirect to parent page with all the values that you want to store in DB.

Comment: If you want to store data that will be accessible by everyone you need a serverside language like php to handle your requests and store them in a database or a file.On the other hand if you dont want to mess with all of those take a look at this: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score 0):

You would at least need a server side language such as PHP.  Using a Database is highly recommended.

In my very humble opinion - Yes, it does sound as if this is over your head right now.

Recommended readings:
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_3?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=php&sprefix=php%2Caps%2C129

Let me know if my answer is helpful.